# Powershell - concatenate strings

Tags: powershell, lines

I try to parse some text files, and at the end I need to make 1 line from 2 lines:

```
19.10.2012 15:33:22<TAB here!>
textline<TAB here!>#1
19.10.2012 15:33:13<TAB here!>
textline<TAB here!>#2
19.10.2012 15:29:29<TAB here!>
textline<TAB here!>#3
19.10.2012 15:29:23<TAB here!>
textline<TAB here!>#4
```

At the output I need to have this:

```
19.10.2012 15:33:22<TAB here!>textline<TAB here!>#1
19.10.2012 15:33:13<TAB here!>textline<TAB here!>#2
19.10.2012 15:29:29<TAB here!>textline<TAB here!>#3
19.10.2012 15:29:23<TAB here!>textline<TAB here!>#4
```

Help me please! :)

EDIT: This is what I have:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Include *.* | Foreach-Object {$_.FullName} |
Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host $_
    $Item = Get-Item $_
        (Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 2 -Encoding UTF8) | Foreach-Object {
        (-join $_)}} | Set-Content $Item -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: I don't use powershell, but a find/replace on "[tab][carriage-return]" would do it.  Easiest non-automated way is to open files in MS Word and replace "^t^p" with "^t".  Most good code editors also accept regex or near equivalents.  `sed` in linux/unix would be easy too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-Content test.txt -ReadCount 2 | 
Foreach-Object { (-join $_) -replace '<TAB here!>',"`t" }
```

Answer (score 0):

One Way:

```
$g = @()
$a = gc .\yourTXTfile.txt

for ($i=0; $i -lt $a.count ; $i+=2)
{ $g += $a[$i]+$a[$i+1] }

$g | set-content .\yournewTXTfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell how to include your script in this construction: `Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Include *.* | Foreach-Object {$_.FullName} |
Foreach-Object {
 Write-Host $_
    $Item = Get-Item $_
    ((Get-Content $Item -Encoding UTF8) -Replace '\d+.\d+.\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ \n', '\d+.\d+.\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ ') | Out-File $Item -Encoding UTF8
}` I try do so by remove EOL characters.. (See after "... -Replace ...